# Implementing scenebuilder into a javafx project

Tags: java, html, maven, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to get a interface from scenebuilder working in my javafx project. I was wondering why I was having issues loading the program when running.

This is my application file

```
package com.example.javafx_project;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    /**
     *
     */
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;
    @FXML
    private Stage stage;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderpane;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        this.stage = stage;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("thisView.fxml"));

        
        this.stage.setTitle("This is it");
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();       

        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

my controller :

```
package com.example.javafx_project;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Label;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class MainDisplayController {
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane pane;
    
    @FXML
    private ToolBar toolbar;

    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;
    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

and my fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.javafx_project.MainDisplayController">
  <top>
     <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
       <items>
         <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      </items>
    </ToolBar>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

my estimation it should be displaying the GUI but it doesn't display anything.

I've tried changing the application loader to hold the thisView.fxml file but it doesn't seem to be loading the GUI that I've created in scenebuilder. Wasn't sure why.

Stack trace:

```
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 20.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 20
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)       
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Label is not a valid type.
/C:/Users/Diane/java-project/SWE3313Proj/JavaFX_Project%20-%20Copy/target/classes/com/example/javafx_project/thisView.fxml:13

        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2718)
        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2850)
        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
        at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531) 
        at com.example.javafx_project/com.example.javafx_project.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:29)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.javafx_project.HelloApplication
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please [edit] your question to add the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627).

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just no display is appearing. But I'll add the stack trace.

Comment: What's your project structure? Is your project managed by `Maven` or `Gradle`?

Comment: Its managed by Maven.

Comment: "_But I'll add the stack trace_" -- The stack trace **is** the error. From that stack trace, we can see the problem is `Label is not a valid type.` In other words, you're missing an import instruction in the FXML file. There should be a `<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>` line. If you've created this FXML file via Scene Builder, then I'm not sure why that import isn't already there.

Comment: Additionally, in your controller class, you should be importing `javafx.scene.control.Button` and `javafx.scene.control.Label` instead of `java.awt.Button` and `java.awt.Label`, respectively. When programming a JavaFX application, avoid importing anything from `java.awt.*` or `javax.swing.*` (unless you're mixing UI frameworks, which should not be done if at all avoidable, and only be done if you know exactly what you're doing).

Comment: Never mark `@FXML` in an application class. That annotation is only used in a controller, which an application class should never be (and is not in your case). Never set an `@FXML` initialized field to a new value.   Never use `@FXML` for a stage type. FXML isn’t used to create stages. Don’t define fields in your classes like VBox or BorderPane when you never use them.  These issues are not the immediate causes of your problems (Slaw already provided those), but will likely cause you or others much confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You are using the wrong imports.

```
Wrong:
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Label;

Correct:
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
```

You must use the JavaFx Button and JavaFX Label, because you are developing with JavaFx and not Java AWT/Swing.